# System.IndexOutOfRangeException for a dynamic initialized array

Tags: c#, arrays

```
var objTypeIndex = from u in context.sistema_DocType_Index where u.docTypeId == id select u.indexId;
indexIds = objTypeIndex.ToList();
int count = indexIds.Count();

string[] names = new string[] {};
int i = 0;                    

foreach (int indexId in indexIds)
{
    //resgata nome do indice e armazena em um array
    string strIndiceID = indexId.ToString();
    int indiceID = Convert.ToInt32(strIndiceID);
    var objIndexName = from u in context.sistema_Indexes where u.id == indiceID select u.idName;
    name = 

    names[i] = objIndexName.First();

    i++;
}
```

This line above the last: 
    names[i] = objIndexName.First();

gives the following error:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

I know what that means.. I just can´t figure out why.

Comment: You're initiating `string[] names` as an empty array, setting `int i = 0`, then accessing `names[i]` - which is `names[0]` - which doesn't exist, since your length is 0, not 1.

Comment: I've removed the MVC/ASP.NET tags as they're irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Why do you take an integer, convert it to a string, and then parse it right back into an int inside of the `foreach` loop?  Just use `indexId` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
string[] names = new string[] {};
```

By

```
var names = new List<string>();
```

And instead of

```
names[i] = objIndexName.First();
```

Use

```
names.Add(objIndexName.First());
```

Then, you will be able to get your array as follow:

```
var nameArray = names.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

Look here:

```
string[] names = new string[] {};
```

You've created an *empty* array. You can't put *any* element into that array. There is no value of `i` for which this statement will work:

```
names[i] = objIndexName.First();
```

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but perhaps you want a `List<string>` to build up (with `Add`) rather than an array? Or you could probably do the whole thing with a single LINQ query...